# translation of open set problem

Tags: general-topology, analysis

Suppose U is an open set in an Euclidean space.

Then any point in U is contained in all but finitely many open sets that is translated by

vectors converging to zero.

It is easily proved in one dimensional euclidean space, but i can't prove it generally...

Answer (score 1):

So, if understand your question correctly, you have an open set $U\subseteq\mathbb R^n$ and a sequence $(v_n)_n$ of vectors in $\mathbb R^n$ satisfying $v_n\to0$ and open sets $U_n$ defined by $U_n=\{u+v_n\mid u\in U\}$. And we have to prove that for every $x\in U$ there exists an $n_0\in\mathbb N$ such that $x$ is contained in $U_n$ for all $n\geq n_0$.

So, let $x\in U$. Now, by definition of Euclidean topology, there exists an $\epsilon>0$ such that for all $y$ satisfying $d(x,y)<\epsilon$, we have $y\in U$. But $(x-v_n)_n$ converges to $x$, so there exists a $n_0$ such that for all $n\geq n_0$ we have $d(x,x-v_n)<\epsilon$, i.e. $x-v_n\in U$. Therefore, $x=(x-v_n)+v_n\in U_n$ also holds for all $n\geq n_0$. This proves the claim.

Comment: I really thank you for your simple and clear solution!